# Javascript Regex: How do I make comma separated numbers optional

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to be able to match a number or a set of numbers separated by commas.

This is what I have right now:

```
/^\d+(?:,\d+)+$/
```

This will match 1,2,3 and will reject a stray comma which is desired.
However, I also need it to match a single number.

any clues?

Comment: Shouldn't that last `+` be a `*` if that last section is not mandatory?

Comment: No problem - I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

That last `+` means you need *at least one* match for the `(?:,\d+)` group. Replace it with a `*` to match 0 or more of those groups:

```
/^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one with look-ahead:

```js
var input = "Try to match 12,34 and number 4 or 5 if needed."
var regex = /(\d+)(?=[,| ]*)/g
var arr   = []
while (m = regex.exec(input)) arr.push(m[1]);
alert(arr)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yF3aT1/1)